# How to add to a new collection from an existing collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

So I am creating a music Player and would like to create an Album Schema from a Song Schema(Already created).

In the Album Schema there is an album title and an array of songs. Now I would like to add the songs to the album if they have the same title.

How do I achieve this?

I have sorted the song collection by album title, but have no clue as how to add the songs to the songs array, if they have the same album title.

```
//This is the song Schema.
var Song = mongoose.model('Songs', {
    album: String,
    title: String,
    artist: String,
    genre: String,
    year: Number,
    src: String
});

//This is the Album Schema.
const AlbumSchema = new Schema({
    album: String,
    songs: [{
        title: String,
        artist: String,
        genre: String,
        year: Number,
        src: String
    }]
});
```

Also is there a way to nest Songs schema in Album schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Blank Array which stores AlbumSchemaObject
let AlbumSchemaArray = [];
//sample Object
let albumObj = {album:"abc",songs:[{title:"abc",artist:"abc",genre:"abc",year:"abc",src:"abc"}]}
//Data from Database
let dataFromMongo = someAlbumObj
//search in already stored Array Object
//if album names exists then fetch that Object
var searchedAlbumObj = AlbumSchemaArray.find((singleObj) => {
                return singleObj.album  === dataFromMongo.album;
            });
//If object match then push songs in that objet
if(typeof(searchedAlbumObj.album) != "undefined")
{
    searchedAlbumObj['songs'].push(dataFromMongo.songs)
}
else //creates new object and stores
{
    AlbumSchemaArray.push(dataFromMongo)
}
```

I have used find method to check object assigned or not. if not we will create new object and push it in one array
if exists, we will fetch that object and push songs to that.
hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

From your schema designs, I am concluding that you have plans of using only one Model (the  'Album' model for Album collection). You have already created a schema for 'Songs'. So, instead of repeating fields in the 'Album' collection, nest 'Songs' schema in 'Album' schema.
You can do it as follows.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Song = mongoose.Schema('Songs', {
   album: String,
   title: String,
   artist: String,
   genre: String,
   year: Number,
  src: String
});

const AlbumSchema = new Schema({
   album: String,
   songs: [Song]
});
```

And then you can create your 'Album model' like,

```
const Album = module.exports = mongoose.model("Album", AlbumSchema);
```

Then wherever(maybe a controller!) you want to create a new song, you can do this,

```
let newSong = {
    album: 'xxx',
    title: 'xxx',
    artist: 'xxx',
    genre: 'xxx',
    year: 'xxx',
    src: 'xxx'
}

Album.update(
    { _id: album._id },
    { $push: { songs: newSong } }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Bharat. But how do I add songs to album schema from my songs schema if they have the same album title? I would like to push the songs with same album in the Songs Array in Album Schema.

Comment: Let's assume you have a front-end app which is adding songs to the album. There when you add a new song, you will select the album. Pass the _id of the album to the back-end. Then you can do the push operation above. Below is the complete code for this. I will update it in the answer too 
let newSong = {
    album: 'xxx',
    title: 'xxx',
    artist: 'xxx',
    genre: 'xxx',
    year: 'xxx',
    src: 'xxx'
}

Album.update(
    { _id: album._id },
    { $push: { songs: newSong } }
);

Comment: @Bharath Op wants to add "from an existing collection"

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a collection of songs, and you need to find songs of a specific album you could use this:

```
Song.find({album: 'foo'})
  .exec()
  .then(songs => {
    return Album.findOneAndUpdate({album: 'foo'}, {$push: {songs: songs}})
      .exec()
  })
  .then(album => console.log(album))
  .catch(err => err);
```

Your Album schema should look like this:

```
const AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  album: String,
  songs: [songSchema]
});
const Song = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);
```

**Example**:

```
songs : [ { _id: 5cb05ecd0facc60f8e383259, album: 'foo', title: 'song1' },
  { _id: 5cb05ecd0facc60f8e38325a, album: 'bar', title: 'song2' },
  { _id: 5cb05ecd0facc60f8e38325b, album: 'foo', title: 'song3' } ]

Song.find({album: 'foo'})
  .exec()
  .then(songs => {
    return Album.findOneAndUpdate({album: 'foo'}, {$push: {songs: songs}})
      .exec()
  })
  .then(album => console.log(album))
  .catch(err => err);

// Code above gives you :

{ _id: 5cb05f8ee567df1092be74a9,
  songs: 
   [ { _id: 5cb05ee5f1a14c0fc23f0c4d,
       album: 'foo',
       title: 'song1',
       __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5cb05ee5f1a14c0fc23f0c4f,
       album: 'foo',
       title: 'song3',
       __v: 0 } ],
  __v: 0,
  album: 'foo' }
```